# SQL Select values from multiple tables and include nulls in the resultset

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-server-2012, duplicates

Consider the following tables and relationships:
[image]

I am trying to create an SQL query that selects:

- Members.lastNotificationCheck
- Polls.pollID
- PollVotes.pollvoteID
- PollVotes.memberID
- PollVotes.date
- Comments.memberID
- Comments.date

For a given memberID in the table Members

And give a resultset that looks something like this:

```
lastNotificationCheck | pollID | pollVoteID | pollvoteMemberID | pollVoteDate | CommentsMemberID | CommentsDate |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          value       | value  |    value   |      value       |     value    |       NULL       | NULL  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          value       | value  |    value   |      value       |     value    |       NULL       | NULL  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          value       | value  |    value   |      value       |     value    |       NULL       | NULL  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          value       | NULL   |    NULL    |      NULL        |     NULL     |       value      | value  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So far I've got this SQL query:

```
SELECT  Polls.pollID,
        Polls.pollTitle,
        PollVotes.memberID AS 'voted_by_id',
        PollVotes.date AS 'vote_date',
        (SELECT membername FROM Members WHERE memberID = PollVotes.memberID) AS 'voted_by_name',
        Comments.date AS 'comment_date',
        Comments.memberID AS 'comment_by_id',
        Comments.messageID,
        (SELECT membername FROM Members WHERE memberID = Comments.memberID) AS 'comment_by_name'
FROM    Members
LEFT OUTER JOIN Polls
    ON Polls.memberID = Members.memberID
LEFT OUTER JOIN PollChoices
    ON PollChoices.pollID = Polls.pollID
LEFT OUTER JOIN PollVotes
    ON PollVotes.pollchoiceID = PollChoices.pollchoicesID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Messages
    ON Messages.memberID = Members.memberID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Comments
    ON Comments.messageID = Messages.messageID

WHERE  Members.memberID = 1964
;
```

The problem is that my resultset repeats the values as a cartesian product of the tables (or something similar. I want to get rid of all duplicates and add NULL values to the fields if no data can be produced.

They above code, generate the following resultset (the top of it):
[image]
As you can see, it repeats a lot of values. Insted of doing this, i'd like it to put in NULL values.

I really hope I've explained my problem clearly enough and that someone can help me solve it.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Btw. i am using MS SQL Server 2012

Comment: Sample data and expected result would be of great help.

Comment: I've updated the question with some output data from the sql query.. Is that what you ment?